# Transaction Listeners throw Nullpointer Exception

Tags: camunda

Since we have updated from camunda engine 7.0.0-alpha4 to 7.0.0-Final, we are facing a problem when rolling back transactions that contain either *deployment* or *delete deployment* commands. The engine defines listeners *DeploymentFailListener* and *DeleteDeploymentFailListener* that are called upon transaction rollback, but at the time of rollback, we are outside camunda's context (i.e. Context has been emptied, and Context.getProcessEngineConfiguration().getRegisteredDeployments() throws a Nullpointer exception).

Is this a bug in the camunda engine? Can we do anything to avoid it?